# How to find out number of possible outcomes by trying over and over?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random, bayesian

While working on my network exploration tool project, I've ran across the problem of reliably determining number of possible exit addresses of a tunnel with single entrance. I've came up with following formulation:

> Given black box with infinite number of marbles of `N` different colors. What is minimal number of marbles should I get out of box to determine `N` with some level of confidence, if each color has the same probability to roll out?

I have no idea to where start from. Maybe this has some relation to Bayes, credible intervals, or confidence intervals? Really, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose after some draws you've seen $k$ different colors.  Furthermore, suppose you haven't seen any new colors in the previous $t$ draws.

If there are more than $k$ colors, the probability that you see a new color within $t$ draws is at least $1-\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^t$.  By letting $t$ (the number of draws since the last ($k^{\text{th}}$) new color was seen) get large, we can make the above probability get very close to 1.  So if you haven't seen a new color, it is likely that there are no new colors to see.

The exact strategy to adopt may depend on how expensive it is to make draws.

Comment: If you want the probability of having missed more colours to be less than some $\alpha$ then this requires $t \gt \dfrac{\log\left(\alpha\right)}{\log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)}$ successive duplicates and for large $k$, $\dfrac{1}{\log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)} \approx -\left(k+\frac12\right)$.  So for example if $k=100$ and your $\alpha=0.01$ then you need at least $463$ successive duplicates after seeing the $100$th colour to decide to stop looking for the $101$st.  This needs to be added to the number you have already seen (a mean of about $518.7$ with a wide dispersion).

Answer (score 1):

If you draw $m$ marbles, the chance that you not have seen a particular color is $\left(\frac {N-1}N \right)^m$, so the chance you have seen it is $1-\left(\frac {N-1}N \right)^m$.  If we make the incorrect assumption that the colors are independent, the chance that you have seen them all is $\left(1-\left(\frac {N-1}N \right)^m\right)^N$  This will be very close when $m$ is rather larger than $N$, as having more than expected of one color will not influence the chance to have seen another color very much.